Parsing AWS CLI outputs
I am using the AWS CLI to list subnets, VPCs and instances to help me get my head round an AWS account with a fair amount of complexity.
How can I parse the log (which looks like JSON) and dump out the essential info to help me see how these items relate to each other?
Python looks like a sensible way to do this, any tips?
VPCs:

command used: aws ec2 describe-vpcs | tee 
array of VPCs
use case: I need a list of VPC names with the associated CIDR Ranges, ideally each VPC & its corresponding CIDR range so I can quickly grep out any "noise" in bash/zsh.
Subnets:
command used: aws ec2 describe-subnets | tee 
nested arrays
list of subnet names with associated CIDR ranges & VPCs, ideally each VPC & its corresponding CIDR range/VPC on one line
Instances:
quickly grep out any "noise" in bash/zsh.
Subnets:
command used: aws ec2 describe-instances | tee 
double nested arrays
list of instances with associated VPCs, ideally each subnet & its corresponding VPC on one line

Tried something that seemed halfway logical and I got this error:
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Is there some reason to just not use boto3?

People generally use the jq utility for parsing JSON output like the AWS CLI outputs on the command line: https://jqlang.github.io/jq/ Although, as others have mentioned, it can be easier to just write some Python code, and if you are doing that, use Boto3 instead of the AWS CLI.

A TypeError is caused by a bug in your Python code. If you want help, you'll need to post the Python code (or a representative subset) and explain where the exception happens.

In case it's helpful: lebinh/aq - Query AWS resources with SQL.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The AWS CLI includes jq-like functionality using --query. For examples, see: JMESPath Tutorial

Extracting VPCs (pass the filename on the command line):
import json
import sys

file = open(sys.argv[1])
jsonString = file.read()
file.close()

jsonObject = json.loads(jsonString)

for item in jsonObject["Vpcs"]:
    for thing in item["Tags"]:
      if (thing["Key"]) == "Name":
        name = {thing["Value"]}

    print (f'CidrBlock: {item["CidrBlock"]} Name: {name} VpcId: {item["VpcId"]}' )

Extracting Subnets:
import json
import sys

file = open(sys.argv[1])
jsonString = file.read()
file.close()

jsonObject = json.loads(jsonString)

for item in jsonObject["Vpcs"]:
    for thing in item["Tags"]:
      if (thing["Key"]) == "Name":
        name = {thing["Value"]}

    print (f'CidrBlock: {item["CidrBlock"]} Name: {name} VpcId: {item["VpcId"]}' )

Extracting instances:
import json
import sys

file = open(sys.argv[1])
jsonString = file.read()
file.close()

jsonObject = json.loads(jsonString)

for item1 in jsonObject["Reservations"]:
  for item2 in item1["Instances"]:
    for item3 in item2["NetworkInterfaces"]:
      for item4 in item2["Tags"]:
        if (item4["Key"]) == "Name":
          name = {item4["Value"]}
          print (f'Name: {name} VpcId: { item3["VpcId"] }' )

These pages were helpful on the way (last first)
Extract single value from JSON data using key
What does "sys.argv[1]" mean? (What is sys.argv, and where does it come from?)
Parse JSON nested array in Python, keep the mapping to the Json object
understanding "item for item in list_a if ..." PYTHON
Extract single value from JSON data using key
https://realpython.com/python-json/

I answered the actual question myself but @mark-b's answer was the answer I didn't know I needed.
I've used jq before a while back but it was so simple and painless that I had forgotten about it :-)  If you want to turn that comment into an answer, so that I can accept it, go for it.
